# Get R^2 from drm analysis and plot lower and upper bounds on a dose response analysis

Tags: r

I would like to know how to obtain the R2 from a dose response analysis.
My script is:

```
test<-drm(control~dose, type, data=test, fct=LL.4())
modelFit (test)
summary (test)# The R2 should appear here?
```

My data:

```
    structure(list(dose = c(6e-04, 6e-04, 6e-04, 6e-04, 6e-04, 6e-04, 
6e-04, 6e-04, 6e-04, 6e-04, 0.0012, 0.0012, 0.0012, 0.0012, 0.0012, 
0.0012, 0.0012, 0.0012, 0.0012, 0.0012, 0.0025, 0.0025, 0.0025, 
0.0025, 0.0025, 0.0025, 0.0025, 0.0025, 0.0025, 0.0025, 0.005, 
0.005, 0.005, 0.005, 0.005, 0.005, 0.005, 0.005, 0.005, 0.005, 
0.01, 0.01, 0.01, 0.01, 0.01, 0.01, 0.01, 0.01, 0.01, 0.01, 0.015, 
0.015, 0.015, 0.015, 0.015, 0.015, 0.015, 0.015, 0.015, 0.015, 
0.02, 0.02, 0.02, 0.02, 0.02, 0.02, 0.02, 0.02, 0.02, 0.02, 0.03, 
0.03, 0.03, 0.03, 0.03, 0.03, 0.03, 0.03, 0.03, 0.03), type = structure(c(1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = "carbamate", class = "factor"), 
    control = c(2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 5L, 1L, 4L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 15L, 
    16L, 14L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 14L, 15L, 19L, 18L, 22L, 22L, 23L, 
    24L, 26L, 22L, 28L, 24L, 28L, 29L, 40L, 49L, 43L, 47L, 43L, 
    41L, 44L, 47L, 49L, 45L, 59L, 57L, 63L, 61L, 59L, 58L, 53L, 
    57L, 56L, 59L, 63L, 63L, 61L, 69L, 68L, 65L, 64L, 63L, 63L, 
    64L, 100L, 87L, 98L, 96L, 93L, 100L, 98L, 96L, 94L, 97L, 
    100L, 100L, 99L, 89L, 98L, 96L, 97L, 93L, 94L, 98L)), .Names = c("dose", 
"type", "control"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -80L
))
```

So, is it possible to plot lower and upper bounds on a dose response analysis like this:

[image]

Comment: Could you add some of your data to make this reproducible?

Comment: Click the edit button under your question, and paste the output of `dput(yourdata)`, `yourdata` being the data frame where your data is stored. Read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) too.